# Is there an R function for creating an interaction plot of a panelAR model?

Tags: r, panel-data, interaction-plot

In order to strengthen the interpretation of an interaction term I would like to create an interaction plot.

*Starting Point:* I am analyzing a panel data frame with which I fitted a feasible generalized least squares model by using the panelAR function. It includes an interaction term of two continuous variables.

*What I want to do:*  To create an interaction plot, e.g. following the style of “plot_model” from the package sjPlot (see Three-Way-Interactions: [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjPlot/vignettes/plot_interactions.html)).

*Problem:* I could neither find any package which supports the type of my model nor a different way to get a plot.

**Question:** Is there any workaround which can be used for obtaining an interaction plot or even a package which supports a panelAR model?

Since I am quite new to R I would appreciate every kind of help. Thank you very much

Comment: please share your code and data so others can help you

Comment: Asking for package recommendations is considered off-topic. It's better to describe your problem in terms of what you have and what you want. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.